# Cannot implement `particles.js`

Tags: javascript, html, particles.js

I am trying to use `particle-js` for my website. My code is quite simple, since it is the very first thing I tried to implement.

My project consists of 4 files: code.html, particles-config.json, particles.js and style.css. With the last one still being empty.

The `code.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="particles.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <p>Test 1</p>
        <div id="particle-div"></div>
        <button id="particle-button">Start</button>
        <p>Test 2</p>
        <script>
            $("#particle-button").click(function(){
                particlesJS.load('particle-div', 'particles-config.json')
            });
    
        </script>
    </header>

  </body>
</html>
```

And the config file is just with the content from the one provided on this [github](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/) under `particle.json`. And the `particle.js` is the exact same file from the github.

However when I run the code, I dont see the particles. It just opens up an empty white space between Test 1 and test2. I amlso not getting any error messages in the browser console (I use Firefox).

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here is a screen shot of the network tab: [image: sc]

Comment: Have you opened the developer console and checked the "Network" tab? Are you sure that the file is served as "text/javascript" in the response header, and you are not encountering a CORS error? Are you running an embedded server like Tomcat or Jetty?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I have added a screen shot of the network tab, to show that now error is being shown. I am running the code with LiveServer on VSC

Comment: have you click on start ?

Comment: Of course I have... You can see sth is changing since the space between Test 1 and 2 is changing (after the click)

Comment: There are many pitfalls in setting this up... My first guess would be that you let the div background to default and since the particles are white ... Please let me know if it's not this, I'll set up a fiddle with your code.

Comment: @kikon thank you for the suggestion, but that did not solve the problem

Comment: Please check this [replit](https://replit.com/@kikon/FirsthandWaterloggedCrypto) around  your code. Besides the background color, another pitfall is using a newer version of `particles.js`. The example you started from uses v 2.0; newer versions expose a different global variable, so in that case you'd get an error about `particlesJS` not being defined.